# Failed assertion: line 4950 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true using showtimepicker widget

Tags: flutter, showtimepicker

I am building to do app and I want to add date in the to do list using showtimepicker widget and I when I did it, the widget appear to me but whenever I press ok or cancel it show me the error above '!_debugLocked': is not true.'

```
TextFormField(
  onTap: 
() {showTimePicker(context: context, initialTime: TimeOfDay.now());}),

  controller: datecontroller,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text
,
  onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
    print(value);
  },
  validator: (String? value) {
    if (value!.isEmpty) {
      return 'date can\'t be empty';
    }
    return null;
  },
);
```

I tried to do a function outside the textfromfield but it didn't work because of the error This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.

Comment: BTW, you're using time picker and not date picker.

Comment: also, you have closed the TextFormField brackets in the wrong place making this code invalid.